# CSS cannot control text alignment , as the whole div seems to move

Tags: html, css, web

How do I move the text to the centre of the images to make it align nicely, because at the moment it isn't aligned at all, it's just sitting at the very bottom. It needs to work for mozilla

```
`<div class="socialMedia">
            <h3>Let's be friends:</h3>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="simple gym facebook"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/email.png" alt="simple gym facebook"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="simple gym facebook"></a>
    </div>`

.socialMedia{
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -moz-box-flex:1;

    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;

    display:-ms-box;
    -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
    -ms-box-flex:1;
    float:right;

}
.socialMedia img{
    padding-right:5px;
}
.socialMedia img:last-child{
    padding-right:0px;
}
.socialMedia h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Times, Arial,serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#b6b5b5;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    display:-moz-box;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, you want the text to sit where?  Moved up a little?

Comment: If they are going to be at a fixed height you could always add `margin:0; line-height: 25px;` to the `h3`.

Comment: i mean to make it align with the centre of the images, because at the moment its aligned with the bottom of the images

Comment: I worked that out and there are 2 solutions already here now.

Comment: I tried your solution Ruddy it didn't work, I FORGOT TO MENTION IT HAS TO WORK FOR MOZZILA

Comment: I put a answer up, both of the answer should work in all browsers. Also I know my way works because I just did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would switch the wrapper to display as a table, and then vertically align middle the table cells.

```
.socialMedia{
    display: table;
}
.socialMedia a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.socialMedia h3 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fms6B/1/)

Comment: this works, however would it be acceptable by a teacher marking the code or would it be considered bad practise?

Comment: Personally I think it is fine. Using tables in your HTML for non-tabular data would be bad practice, but here we're just styling the containers to get the behavior we want.

Comment: Recheck your code, there was a typo in my CSS: `.socialMedia img a` should have been `.socialMedia a`.

Comment: done, thanks, is there a way you could check my code(its 450+ lines) because what i'm doing now is a result of failing to make my web compatible with firefox. The flex box model worked perfect with safari and chrome, but looked completely messed up in firefox, so now i am changing a lot of stuff, so i was wondering maybe there is an alternative solution instead of removing specific flex box -moz- code from the css

Comment: Do you have a link I could take a look at?

Answer (score 1):

Using `1ine-height` is an option for this if you will be using a fixed height. The only thing I changed was the `H3` adding `line-height: 25px;` and getting rid of the `H3` margin using `margin: 0;`.

### HTML:

```
<div class="socialMedia">
     <h3>Let's be friends:</h3>
 <a href="#"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="simple gym facebook" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="images/email.png" alt="simple gym facebook" /></a>
 <a href="#"><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="simple gym facebook" /></a>

</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.socialMedia {
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    display:-ms-box;
    -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
    -ms-box-flex:1;
    float:right;
}
.socialMedia img {
    padding-right:5px;
}
.socialMedia img:last-child {
    padding-right:0px;
}
.socialMedia h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Times, Arial, serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#b6b5b5;
    margin:0;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/N7xQV/)